# Why i have to do "double submit" in my search form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms

I'm currently working on a form that allows users to search for bills by their description, ID, or price. However, I've encountered an issue: after the initial search, I have to submit the form twice to get the desired results.

`getBillsByIdDescriptionPrice(formState.search)`
is a function that brings from de DB all the `bills` that match with the content from the input `formState.search`

The first search usually works fine. However, upon the second search, after submitting the query, it initially returns all the data instead of the specific result I'm looking for. Only after submitting the form again does it finally bring up the correct data.

Doing console logs, I noticed that during the second search, it briefly returns the correct result. However, shortly after, it reverts to displaying all the data, requiring an additional submission.

Video of how it works: https://www.loom.com/share/7566d93238934c18a1efbaeb42deab8c?sid=be8383a1-da5d-41d7-9481-a09045c7e31e

I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot!

React with Typescript and Material UI

Link to the repo: https://github.com/guidomora/facturacion-front/blob/main/src/billing/components/BillingSearch.tsx

Here you can check the code:

```
 const { bills, getBillsByIdDescriptionPrice } = useContext(DataContext)
  const { formState, inputChange, search } = useFormSearch({ search: '' })

  const handleSubmit =  (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (formState.search === '') return
    getBillsByIdDescriptionPrice(formState.search)
    
  }

  const submitButton = () => {
    if (formState.search === '') return
    getBillsByIdDescriptionPrice(formState.search)
  }


{/* displayed data */}
      {(bills.length === 0) ? <Typography variant='h5' 
      sx={{ textAlign: 'center', color: 'black', fontWeight: 600, mt: 35 }}>
        No bills found...
      </Typography> :
        <BillingTable bills={bills} />
      }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre]. Links to off site code repositories are not appropriate

Comment: Show how you are briefly getting the data. Share the code for `getBillsByIdDescriptionPrice`

Answer (score 0):

I'm feeling like you need to change your submit button to a real submit button `<button type="submit">` that submits the form. Then you can remove it's click event handler and need only one submit handler.

I also think there's a possibility that you're getting a stale state in the `useFormSearch` component.  Instead of spreading state into the state setter

```
 setFormState({
      ...formState,
      [name]: numericValue,
    });
```

you should use the functional method of setting state like so.

```
 setFormState((prev)=> {
      ...prev,
      [name]: numericValue,
    });
```

That will guarantee that you're never grabbing a stale state.

Comment: I tried changing the code but it had no effect on the search. I added a video of how the app works so you can see